cython on aarch64 (x86) painfully slow
I have a python program that I've been working with for a long time now on an x86 mac. I have since moved to an m3 mac. I still need to be producing an x86 binary with cython and pyinstaller, so am following the same process as before. I have installed the x86 version of python, so it's all running under Rosetta.
My problem is that it takes forever (eg hours (m3 mac) vs minutes on an x86 mac) for cython to build the .so files (.c file creation time seems ok). Has anyone else experienced this and have a suggestion on how to speed up?
